# windbg: stepping into dll of a process

Tags: debugging, dll, reverse-engineering, windbg

Newb-question here. I have searched a couple days for the solution but dont't get anywhere. Using windbg preview.

There's a process that loads a dll and I want to see the disassembly of the addresses that are called from inside the dll. No symbols available because it is third party. I can find the entry point and break on it but after that I cannot step into the dll. I know I need to load the dll into windbg but I can't put it in the arguments when I start the exe because I only know the entry point after the module is loaded.
If I use .load on my dll and set a breakpoint on entry it doesn't work either.
Anyone done this before and can tell me what I need to do to step into the dll's assembly?

edit:
In windbg I launched the executable (.exe) and want to see the addresses and operations inside a .dll that are called during a specific operation in the program.

Comment: since you tagged this windbg use wt command bp function inyour exe bp next instruction wt also check inclusions and exclusions if plain wt is taking too long

Comment: This is a third party dll so I don't have any symbols for the exe or the dll file. tried wt but it doesn't show me any offsets called. only the name of the dll instead of function locations

Answer (score 1):

Simple things first: `.load` is for loading WinDbg Plugins into the WinDbg process. That's not what you want.

I'm assuming that you want to do more a reverse engineering than debugging. WinDbg is not ideal for this task. There are certainly better tools like IDA.

#### Analyzing without executing

But anyway, let's get into it. I'll choose an arbitrary DLL for this example. It is a DLL provided with the AMD display driver, `C:\AMD\PSP Driver\WTx64\amdtee_api32.dll` and I have no clue about it.

1. Open WinDbg Preview
2. Go to "Open dump file" (this is not really intuitive, but it will work)
3. In the file open dialog, enter `*`, so DLLs will be displayed (by default it's limited to DMP files)
4. Choose the DLL to be loaded

At this point, it will say

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.21349.1004 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Loading Dump File [C:\AMD\PSP Driver\WTx64\amdtee_api32.dll]
```

You can now operate on the DLL with the same commands as during a live debugging session.

```
0:000> lm
start    end        module name
10000000 10055000   amdtee_api32   (export symbols)       amdtee_api32.dll
```

So I have no PDB file available, just export symbols, as there are:

```
0:000> x *!*
7ffe0300          SharedUserData!SystemCallStub = <no type information>
10001050          amdtee_api32!TEEC_InitializeContext (<no parameter info>)
[...]
```

And we can disassemble a function:

```
0:000> uf amdtee_api32!TEEC_InitializeContext
amdtee_api32!TEEC_InitializeContext:
10001050 55              push    ebp
10001051 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
10001053 83ec08          sub     esp,8
10001056 c745f801000000  mov     dword ptr [ebp-8],1
1000105d 837d0c00        cmp     dword ptr [ebp+0Ch],0
10001061 750a            jne     amdtee_api32!TEEC_InitializeContext+0x1d (1000106d)  Branch
[...]
```

You can even access the memory where the DLL is loaded to

```
0:000> db amdtee_api32
10000000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
10000010  b8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........@.......
10000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
10000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 10 01 00 00  ................
10000040  0e 1f ba 0e 00 b4 09 cd-21 b8 01 4c cd 21 54 68  ........!..L.!Th
10000050  69 73 20 70 72 6f 67 72-61 6d 20 63 61 6e 6e 6f  is program canno
10000060  74 20 62 65 20 72 75 6e-20 69 6e 20 44 4f 53 20  t be run in DOS 
10000070  6d 6f 64 65 2e 0d 0d 0a-24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  mode....$.......
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tried finding the relevant functions in ghidra but the dll is relatively huge. So I wanted to see which addresses in the dll are called by the process during the relevant program operations. is there no way of stepping into the dll when I hit the entry breakpoint in live debugging?

Comment: @d8613r: so, you already have an EXE that loads the DLL and runs it?

Comment: yes that's right. The exe loads the dll when I start the program but it is used for many operations in the program. I'm only looking for some functions inside the dll that are used in a specific operation of the exe. i can break when these get to the entry of the dll but then I don't know how to make these specific addresses of the dll visible